# When I'm visiting another page, The images, logos, and icons are not displayed. In this project, I'm using the pug template engine and express.js

Tags: node.js, express, webserver, pug

When I'm visiting another page, images, logos, and icons are not displayed, but when I'm went back to the home page, images are displayed perfectly

In this project, I have used the pug template engine and express.js

**Below link is the image of the project folder and files**

[Project folder and files image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qykPQ.png)

**Below link is the image of the home page**

images, logos, and icons are displayed perfectly, but on the login and signup page I'm facing a problem with images

[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW5i9.jpg)

**Below link is the image of the login and singup page**

On this page, images are not displayed **Problem!**

[login and singup page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGYXK.png)

**Below section is express.js code**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 80;
const path = require('path');

// <------------------ define static mode  ------------------>

*// app.use(express.static('public'));*

const staticpath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
app.use(express.static(staticpath));

// <------------------ Adding pug engine in express  ------------------>
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../view'));

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.status(200).render('index.pug');
})

app.get('/loginandsingup.pug', (req, res)=>{
    res.status(200).render('loginandsingup.pug');
})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
     console.log(`application had started successfully on port ${port}`)
})
```

**below section is pug code of home page**

```
.img#menu-icon
  img(src="images/menu-icon.svg", alt="Menu icon")
#navbarSupportedContent.collapse.navbar-collapse
  .logo
    a(href="/")
      img(src="images/logo.png", alt="entre logo")
  ul.navUl.navbar-nav.mb-2.mb-lg-0
    li#nav-item-1.navList.nav-item
      a.navLink.nav-link.text-dark(href="#") Home
    li#nav-item-1.navList.nav-item
      a.navLink.nav-link.text-dark(href="#") Order
```

**Below section is pug code of login and singup page**

```
.img#menu-icon
    img(src="./menu-icon.svg", alt="Menu icon")
  #navbarSupportedContent.collapse.navbar-collapse
    .logo
      a(href="/")
        img(src="./logo.png" alt="entre logo")
    ul.navUl.navbar-nav.mb-2.mb-lg-0
      li#nav-item-1.navList.nav-item
        a.navLink.nav-link.text-dark(href="#") Home
      li#nav-item-1.navList.nav-item
        a.navLink.nav-link.text-dark(href="#") Order
```

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Put all the files you want to access through your website in a folder called `public`, and in your server file write `app.use(express.static("public"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **1. Add this middleware in the `app.js` above you set view engine**

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

### **2. Folder Structure**

```
|__public/   
    |__ css/
        |__ css files...
    |__ js/
        |__ js files...
```

### **3. Import this way**

Now you set the path to the public directory you have to give the path public folder when you import

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
```

### **NOTE:-**

One more thing public directory in root and also `app.js` file should be in the root if you want `app.js` in src then set path accordingly

## **You should now be all set up to access CSS or any file**